# Regex - Match multiple instances of specific character thats not followed by numeric value

Tags: regex

I need a regex query to match the following:

```
hello%20world //Wont match
hello % dog //Will match
hello %20 world //Wont match
hello %% world //Will match but twice (Wont match as whole word of %%, will match single "%" and then the second "%")
```

I am using regex to replace any matches of "%" that is not followed by a number. If it contains "%%", i also want to replace both of those with lets say 'A' so i get "AA" not "A".

My regex attempt:

```
%[^0-9]
```

https://regex101.com/r/Z9N7QJ/1

Issue is its matching but also with the next character so my string "Hello % world" matches "% ". And my "%%" is being matched as a pair not singles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead here:

```
/%(?!\d)/
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9N7QJ/2)

Lookahead is a **Zero width match** but your regex `%[^0-9]` on the contrary consumes next non numeric character as well.